# Test of file existence always fails

Tags: php

```
<?
$user_image = '../images/users/' . $userid . 'a.jpg';
if (file_exists($user_image)) 
{
    echo '<img src="'.$user_image.'" alt="" />';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<img src="../images/users/small.jpg" alt="" />';
}
?>
```

Hello all, this code is supposed to check for a file and if it doesnt work, display another.
For some reason it is ALWAYS displaying the placeholder and never finds the initial file even though it is there.
Is there something obviously not right here?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you tried using a path from the root user directory instead of a relative path?

Comment: Current working directory is possibly not what you expect, what does a realpath('../images/users/') give you, or the output of getcwd() ?

Comment: have you checked what value $user_images has? e.g. echo ($user_image)

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something more related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [realpath](http://php.net/realpath) and [dirname](http://php.net/dirname) instead.

```
<?
$user_image = '../images/users/' . $userid . 'a.jpg';
if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . $user_image))) 
{
    echo '<img src="'.$user_image.'" alt="" />';
} 
else 
{
    echo '<img src="../images/users/small.jpg" alt="" />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

the PHP is running in a different directory.  try `echo getcwd();`

Answer (score 4):

[`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) does not work with relative paths. Try something like this:

```
$user_image = $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'}.'/../images/users/' . $userid . 'a.jpg';
if (file_exists($user_image))
// blah blah
```

But, as Artefacto suggests, it's better to use the real path:

```
$user_image = '/path/to/your/files/images/users/' . $userid . 'a.jpg';
```

It's easier to maintain since you can use that code on different PHP scripts located on different directories without having to change anything.

Comment: "file_exists does not work with relative paths": that's simply wrong, and easily refuted with `var_dump(file_exists("."));`

Answer (score 2):

If your relative path points outside of the htdocs subdirectories, then the image will not be sent by the webserver

Answer (score 0):

I mean I'm not always the smartest with php, but is your concat location correct? Because right now, won't it resolve to /images/users/userida.jpg ? is this really what you want?

Comment: No, it will resolve to: '../images/users/123a.jpg' if $userid is '123'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check to see what `realpath('../images/users/' . $userid . 'a.jpg')` returns. I get the feeling it has something to do with the relative path